# Add an Anchor link to a Div AND its Pseudo Element (CSS or Javascript / jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, anchor, pseudo-element

I have an anchor link on a menu with an icon above it.  I need it so that when someone clicks on either the menu item, or the pseudo element above it holding the icon, the link works.

I have a codepen here: http://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/wJrqaR

The red square is the pseudo element that will hold the icon.

The code is:

CSS

```
.menu {
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    background: blue;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 0px;
}

.menu-item1 a { color: white; text-decoration: none; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu menu-item1"><a href="//google.com">Menu Item</a></div>
```

Any help would be awesome.

Emily.

Comment: Use `.menu a:before` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RpLZMe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white; 
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:before {
  content:'icon';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="//google.com">Google</a>
  <a href="//yandex.com">Yandex</a>
</div>
```